# how the uncertainty of the coefficient in the model affect the uncertainty of the fit

Tags: nonlinear-regression, uncertainty

I am wondering how to estimate the uncertainty of the fit if the coefficients in the model have uncertainties as well. for example:

I try to use model **y=exp(-(a+b)*x)+c** to fit a data set **x** and **y** to find out the value of **b** and **sigma_b**, where **a** and **c** are predetermined coefficients and have uncertainty **sigma_a** and **sigma_c** , how should I do it??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A minor but important clarification is needed: are all the values of $a$ (or $c$) associated with each pair $(x_i,y_i)$ the *same* or can they differ from one observation to the next?

Comment: @whuber,  all the values of **a** (or **c**) associated with each pair _(xi,yi)_ are the same.

Comment: @ whuber, do you have any reference for this type of questions? your help is greatly appreciated.